# Parse Email Body with Multiple Lines

Tags: javascript, parsing, name-value

How would I go about parsing a email body with multiple lines in javascript?

Example

```
Employee:

123456789

Name:

John Doe
```

This is what I'm using right now.

```
var emailObj = {};

var body_text = inputs.email.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, ""); 
var regEx = /^(.+):(.+)$/;


for (var i = 0; i < valPairs.length; i++) {
  matches = valPairs[i].match(regEx);
  emailObj[matches[1].toString().trim()] = matches[2].toString().trim(); 
}

outputs.email_var = emailObj;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first filter out the empty lines by splitting by a newline and using [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

The object can be constructed by using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and checking whether the index is even or not. If it is, set the property name and value to the according items in the array.

```js
const str = `Employee:

123456789

Name:

John Doe`;

const lines = str.split("\n").filter(e => e != "");

const obj = lines.reduce((a, b, i) => {
  if (i % 2 != 0) {
    a[lines[i - 1]] = lines[i]
  }
  return a;
}, {})

console.log(obj)
```